# How can I get access to token price data at a specific block?

Tags: price

Apologies if this is a daft question but from some searching on Google I'm not able to find the answers I'm looking for (maybe I'm not searching for the right thing).

I want to be able to access the price data for a specific token (doesn't matter which, needs to be user specified), at a particular block from Eth's on-chain data.

I.e. I want to supply a block number and a token address and I want to get back the price that specific token had at that block.

Is this possible? And if so is it possible through ethers.js or do I need to use something else?

Comment: Usually contracts do not have historical prices to consult on-chain. You could store the prices you will be using in a contract if you want.

Answer (score 3):

You should have `archive` node. Only then you can query the blockchain at specific block number. Regarding the prices you have 2 options:

1. Oracles, like [Chainlink's price feeds](https://data.chain.link/ethereum/mainnet/crypto-usd). For example, call the `latestAnswer` at specific block number in contract [`0x5f4ec3df9cbd43714fe2740f5e3616155c5b8419`](https://etherscan.io/address/0x5f4ec3df9cbd43714fe2740f5e3616155c5b8419) und you'll get the `ETH` price.
2. Not for all tokens you find oracles and price feeds, then you have to query the DEXes yourself, like `Uniswap`. Again, at a specific block get the reserves for the pair and its ratio gives you the price. *The reserves are in `wei`, so convert to `ether`, as tokens may have different `decimals` values.*

---

This should answer the question, but I have also decided to write an article about this: https://dev.kit.eco/ethereum-get-token-price-at-a-specific-block-onchain

Answer (score 0):

For uniswap with graph you can make query like this to https://api.thegraph.com/subgraphs/name/uniswap/uniswap-v2:

```
{
    pair(id: "0x0599282297a15ca86a10dabfc2bd5781f610e246", block: {number: 18785131}){
        token0 {
            id
            symbol
            name
            decimals
            derivedETH
            tradeVolume
            totalLiquidity
            tradeVolumeUSD
            untrackedVolumeUSD
        }
        token1 {
            id
            symbol
            name
            derivedETH
        }
        reserve0
        reserve1
        reserveUSD
        trackedReserveETH
        token0Price
        token1Price
        volumeUSD
        txCount
    }
}
```